# Override createToolTip() method of JPanel in java swing

Tags: java, swing, tooltip, jpanel

I have a `ListCellRenderer` which extends `JPanel`. Now I try to override its `createToolTip()`. But it seems like method is not getting overridden. What could be the reason?

My Code:

```
public class MyRender extends JPanel implements ListCellRenderer {

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,
            int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        if (value != null) {
            removeAll();

            // -- add data to JPanel.

            setToolTipText("hi");
            return this;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public JToolTip createToolTip() {
        System.out.println("Success");
        return new MyToolTip();
    }
}
```

It doesn't even prints "Success".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this method is never called because the `ListCellRenderer` acts as a "**rubber stamp**", hence it exists only during repaint, and is never added to any container, in particular not the `JList` it is assigned to.

Thus, the tooltip is always created by the `JList` itself, never the `ListCellRenderer`.

If you want to have a special tooltip for every item in your list, then there are several ways, the easiest (but maybe not the nicest) is probably to subclass `JList` and override `getToolTipText(MouseEvent e)`. That method received the mouse coordinates for which to get the tooltip, you'll have to convert them to the index of the item over which the mouse is, by using `locationToIndex()`.

Comment: how to get mouse co-ordinate in `getToolTipText()` ?

Comment: in the `MouseEvent` passed as argument.

Comment: Okay got it. Actually first I have override the default `getToolTipText()` that is without any arguments.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I hadn't paid attention to the other method.